# How to restrict access to Visual SVN server by specified IP address?

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008-r2, svn, visualsvn-server

I need to allow only specific IP addrees to access my visual svn server.

Visual SVN 2.6.0 is installed in the server.
SERVER : WIndows 2008 R2

I'm accessing the svn by the urls like https://example.com:8443/svn/reponame

I've IIS7 on this same server with a site running as https://example.com

Comment: Do you need limit access to VisualSVN Server only from specific IP address or bind VisualSVN Server to specific interfaces? It seems to be possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799991/how-can-i-set-only-internal-ips-of-the-company-to-be-accessible-with-visualsvn-s/17804432#17804432

Comment: Thank you @IvanZhakov I need to limit access to VisualSVN Server only from specific IP address

Comment: Not duplicate.. because its not internal network... SVN is in a dedicated server hosted in another country and accessing through a domain name like in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [ACLs in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) (server behind the scene of VisualSVN Server)

Add related directives (by hand) into httpd.conf

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from IP.OF.ALLOWED.HOST
```

Create backup of your custom config in order to restore changes after server's update

Comment: Do not modify `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd.conf`. Use `httpd-custom.conf` instead.